# About search query

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie in web development.
I have a task on search result.

If someone searches on my website like "God is Great with us", I want the results to show first "God is Great with us" if this string matches perfectly, then
"god" related name product, if any, then
"great" related name product, if any, then
"with" related name product, if any

We have to discard less than 2 characters.

I have laravel 5.5 and phpmyadmin pdo

***What I tried:***

```
$search="God is Great with us"
$multiSearch  = explode(" ", $search);
$multiSearch1 = [];
foreach ($multiSearch as $work) {
    if (strlen($work) <= 2) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $multiSearch1[] = $work;
    }
}

array_unshift($multiSearch1, $search);
foreach ($multiSearch1 as $term) {
    $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . strtoupper($term) . '%');
}
return $query;
```

but my result is not shown in proper order

"strtoupper function" is use because proudct name is save in uppercase

Comment: if any one find best method please reply me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the issue is that you want to rank the results, starting with the whole phrase. The issue is that MySQL doesn't return the results in any guaranteed order. That is...

`SELECT last_name FROM customers WHERE last_name LIKE 'A%' OR last_name LIKE 'B%' OR last_name LIKE 'C%';`

...may return...

```
last_name
---------
Babu
Agarwal
Chabra
```

To get the order you want, you need to use a series of UNION queries to ensure the right order, like this:

```
$words = explode(" ", $search);
$multiSearch=[];
foreach($words as $word){
    if(strlen($word)<=2){
        continue;
    } else {
        $multiSearch[]=$word;
    }
}

// Start the query with the whole search term
$query = DB:table('products')
    ->select(DB:raw('1 as displayOrder, name')
    ->where('name', 'like', '%' . strtoupper($search) . '%');

$displayOrder=2;
foreach ($multiSearch as $term){
    // Make a new query for each word, each with a greater display order
    $wordQuery = DB:table('products')
        ->select(DB:raw($displayOrder . ' as displayOrder, name');

    // Add this word's query to the main query
    $query->union('$wordQuery');
    $displayOrder++;
}

// This query will now be a union of each search, ordered as you wish
$query->orderBy(displayOrder', 'name');
```